# Regularisation of supersymmetric two-point function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, complex-numbers, dirac-delta-distributions

In four-dimensional Minkowski space, one of the building blocks for two-point functions in CFTs is the squared modulus of the separation between the two points $x_1$ and $x_2$,
$$x_{12}^2 = x_{12}^ax_{12}^b\eta_{ab}~,\qquad x_{12}^a:=(x_1-x_2)^a~,\qquad \eta_{ab}=\text{diag}(-,+,+,+)$$
For example, the two-point function of a (primary, weight 1) complex scalar field $\phi(x)$ and its conjugate is
$$\langle \phi(x_1) \bar{\phi}(x_2)\rangle \propto \frac{1}{x_{12}^2}~.$$
This is singular in the coincident limit $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$, and hence the expression $\frac{1}{x_{12}^2}$ is usually understood as a generalised function implicitly containing the $i\varepsilon$ prescription $\frac{1}{x_{12}^2+i\varepsilon}$.

In order to regularise and extract the divergent part of (powers of) $(x_{12}^2+i\varepsilon)^{-1}$, a useful identity is given in the book https://www.amazon.com.au/Generalized-Functions-Properties-Operations-Publishing/dp/1470426587 by Gelfand and Shilov (see section 2.4 of ch 3, p.g. 276). Namely, consider a non-degenerate quadratic form $P=g_{ab}x^ax^b$ with real coefficients $g_{ab}$ (which may be more general than $\eta_{ab}$). Then the generalised function $(P+i\varepsilon)^{\lambda}$ is a regular analytic function of $\lambda$ everywhere except at $\lambda = -2-k$, for $k=0,1,2,\dots$, where it has simple poles with residues given by
$$\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{\lambda = -2-k} \big(P+i\varepsilon\big)^{\lambda}= \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi q i}\pi^2}{2^{2k}k!(k+1)!\sqrt{|\text{det}(g_{ab})|}}\big(g^{cd}\partial_c\partial_d\big)^k\delta^4(x) \tag{1}$$
Here $q$ is the number of negative eigenvalues of $g_{ab}$. Using this one may show, e.g., that the divergent part of $\frac{1}{(x_{12}^2)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(x_{12}^2)^3}$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(x_{12}^2)^2}\Big|_{\text{div}}=-i\pi^2\delta^4(x_{12})~,\qquad \frac{1}{(x_{12}^2)^3}\Big|_{\text{div}}=-\frac{i\pi^2}{8}\Box\delta^4(x_{12})~.
\end{align}

**My question**

In $4d$ supersymmetric CFTs, the analogue of the two-point building block $\frac{1}{x_{12}^2}$ is $\frac{1}{x_{\bar{1}2}^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x_{\bar{2}1}^2}$, where
$$x_{\bar{1}2}^a := x^a_{1-}-x_{2-}^a+2i\theta_{2}\sigma^{a}\bar{\theta}_1~, \qquad x_{\pm}^a:=x^a\pm i \theta \sigma^a\bar{\theta}~. $$
See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9808041 for more details. Is there a result analogous to (1) in the supersymmetric case? It is not obvious to me how I can adapt identity (1) to the case of the quadratic form $P=\eta_{ab}x_{\bar{1}2}^ax_{\bar{1}2}^b$ or $P=\eta_{ab}x_{\bar{2}1}^ax_{\bar{2}1}^b$ for $k>0$ (in particular the operator $g^{cd}\partial_c\partial_d$ troubles me).

Comment: Just express it as a polynomial in grassman coordinates, and apply (1) term-by-term to the bosonic parts.